# AttributeError: Flag --trained_checkpoint_prefix must be specified

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use object_detection model with tf 1.4. I realize that there is no training directory that used to contain some ckpt files as in the previous tf versions, so any suggestions where is the new destination or should I use the ones from old versions?

I'm using the below command

python3 export_inference_graph.py \
    --input_type image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config \
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix model.ckpt \
    --output_directory inference

Answer (score 0):

You can download the full sets including the .ckpt files from [this link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)